# Почему cURL не парсит определенный сайт

Tags: php, curl

Есть такая функция cURL:

```
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

Хочу получить html код страницы сайта: https://www.blockchain.com/ru/

Делаю так:

```
$html = curl("https://www.blockchain.com/ru/");
echo $html;
```

В ответ ничего не приходит. А любой другой сайт - парсит.

Как обойти это и получить html код? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Иногда, если домен содержит ssl-сертификат, то curl требует дополнительных опций при запросе

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https

Также всегда есть вариант, что Вас `забанили`

Comment: получаю такое сообщение об ошибке: `error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version`

Comment: Значит проблема не в сертификате. Ваш код, на моем компьютере, отрабатывает без проблем: я получаю ответ 200 и код страницы
Имею `php7.2 + php7.2-curl`

Comment: также возможен вариант, что вас забанили. попробуйте сменить IP

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте генерировать Cookie. На Reg.Ru прекрасно срабатывает.

```
<?php

function curl_cookie($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT     , 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT   5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.4) Gecko/20091016 Firefox/3.5.4');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');    

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

//$html = file_get_contents('https://www.blockchain.com/ru/'); //тоже срабатывает
$html = curl_cookie('https://www.blockchain.com/ru/');
echo $html;
//echo htmlspecialchars($html); //-вывести html код

?>
```